# Factory property not updating in controller

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api, factory

I have a property in my factory and a sync() method to update it, but when accessing from controller the value never changes.

My router: (Initialise events with resolve)

```
'use strict';

myApp

.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'header': {
        controller: 'HeaderCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/header/_header.html'
      },
      'footer': {
        templateUrl: 'views/footer/_footer.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.events', {
    url: '^/',
    views: {
      'content@': {
        controller: 'EventsCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/events/_events.html',
        resolve: {
          postPromise: ['EventsServ', function(EventsServ) {
            return EventsServ.getAll();
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.about', {
    url: '^/sobre',
    views: {
      'content@': {
        templateUrl: 'views/about/_about.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.contact', {
    url: '^/contato',
    views: {
      'content@': {
        controller: 'ContactCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/contact/_contact.html'
      }
    }
  });

}]);
```

My controller: (Now sync with facebook and update events)

```
'use strict';

myApp

.controller('EventsCtrl', ['$scope', 'EventsServ', '$filter', '$window', 'Facebook', 'postPromise', '$log', '$timeout', function($scope, EventsServ, $filter, $window, Facebook, postPromise, $log, $timeout) {

  $scope.alerts = [];
  $scope.events = EventsServ.all(); // <<<< Never update, keep the same value obtained in router.
  $scope.periods = [{
    label: 'HOJE',
    labelColor: 'success',
    startTime: $filter('clearTime')(new Date()),
    endTime: $filter('clearTime')(new Date()),
    events: []
  }, {
    label: 'PRÓXIMOS DIAS',
    labelColor: 'primary',
    startTime: $filter('clearTime')($filter('addDay')(new Date(), 1)),
    endTime: $filter('clearTime')($filter('addDay')(new Date(), 8)),
    events: []
  }, {
    label: 'PRÓXIMAS SEMANAS',
    labelColor: 'warning',
    startTime: $filter('clearTime')($filter('addDay')(new Date(), 9)),
    events: []
  }];

  if (postPromise.status >= 200 && postPromise.status < 300) {
    angular.forEach($scope.events, (function(event) {
      var eventDate = $filter('clearTime')(event.start_time);
      angular.forEach($scope.periods, (function(period) {
        if (eventDate >= period.startTime && (eventDate <= period.endTime || !period.endTime)) {
          period.events.push(event);
        }
      }));
    }));
    Facebook.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if(response.status === 'connected') {
        EventsServ.sync();
        $log.info($scope.events);
      } else {
        $log.info('notLoggedIn');
      }
    });
  } else {
    $scope.alerts.push({
      type: 'danger',
      msg: 'Ooops! Não foi possível buscar os eventos.'
    });
  }

  $scope.openEvent = function(event) {
    $window.open('http://facebook.com/events/' + event.id, '_blank');
  };

  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };

}])

.filter('addDay', function() {
  return function(date, days) {
    return new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + days));
  };
})

.filter('clearTime', function() {
  return function(date) {
    var d = new Date(date);
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    return d;
  };
});
```

I build my view looping through $scope.events.

My factory:

```
'use strict';

myApp

.factory('EventsServ', ['$http', '$q', 'Facebook', 'PagesServ', '$log', function($http, $q, Facebook, PagesServ, $log) {

  var factory = {
    events: []
  };

  factory.all = function() {
    return factory.events;
  };

  factory.getAll = function() {
    return $http.get('/events.json')
      .success(function(response) {
        angular.copy(response, factory.events);
      })
      .error(function(response) {
        $log.error('Failed to get events.');
      });
  };

  factory.sync = function() {
    PagesServ.getAll().then(function(response) {
      var pages = PagesServ.pages;
      var events = [];
      var pagesPromises = [];
      var eventsPromises = [];

      angular.forEach(pages, function(page, key) {
        pagesPromises.push(Facebook.api(page.facebook_id, function(response) {
          page.facebook_id = response.id;
          page.name = response.name;
          page.image = 'image.jpg';
          delete page.events;
          delete page.created_at;
          delete page.updated_at;
        }));

        eventsPromises.push(Facebook.api(page.facebook_id + '/events', function(response) {
          var pageEvents = response.data;
          angular.forEach(pageEvents, function(event, key) {
            event.page = page;
          });
          events = events.concat(pageEvents);
        }));
      });

      $q.all(pagesPromises).then(function() {
        $log.info(pages);
      }, function(reason) {
        $log.error('Failed to syncs pages: ' + reason);
      });

      $q.all(eventsPromises).then(function() {
        factory.events = [];
        angular.forEach(events, function(event, key) {
          var eventSynced = {
            facebook_id: event.id,
            image: '',
            name: event.name,
            description: event.description,
            start_time: event.start_time,
            end_time: event.end_time,
            going: 397,
            address: '...',
            page: event.page
          }
          factory.events.push(eventSynced);
        });
        $log.info(factory.events); // <<<<< Here the new value is correct!
      }, function(reason) {
        $log.error('Failed to syncs events: ' + reason);
      });
    });
  };

  return factory;

}]);
```

The new value of the property inside factory is correct when printing to console, but in controller the value never changes, is always [ ].

Comment: Just wondering. If you change the order of the statements what happens?

Comment: Is your sync function called from inside the same controller where your factory object is instantiated? - if you are calling them across two controllers, each one will have a copy of your factory object

Comment: Try wrapping this line : factory.events.push(eventSynced); - with apply. $scope.$apply(function() { factory.events.push(eventSynced) });

Comment: If I change the order nothing happens. Yes, all in the same controller!

Comment: Wrapping with apply didn't work.

Comment: I assume you wrap the code above in an angular factory? Such as, angular.module("app").factory("EventsServ", function () { return factory; }). Show that code perhaps.

Comment: A cut down version of this works fine. Still suggest it has to do with the Facebook calls happening outside of angular. Try to wrap the, EventsServ.sync() in the controller with either an $timeout or $apply. DIfficult to test

Comment: Test the closure by passing the instantiated object to the function like `EventsServ.sync(EventsServ)` and in your factory `factory.sync = function(self) {` and `self.events.push(eventSynced)`

Answer (score 0):

When have data I want to stay in sync between a controller and a factory, or a factory and multiple controllers, I set the data item I want to access in my controller to the object or array in the factory:

```
    // in your controller change this
    $scope.events = EventsServ.all();
    // to use the object
    $scope.events = EventsServ.events;
```

In your sync function where you are iterating over the events, push each one into a temporary array, then use angular.copy to make the update to the array available to the controller.

```
    // at the line right before you log the events in the factory use
    angular.copy(tempArray, factory.events);
    $log.info(factory.events);
```

More info: http://www.justinobney.com/keeping-angular-service-list-data-in-sync-among-multiple-controllers/